# Copy constructor and cascaded function calls

Tags: c++, function, c++11, copy-constructor

I ran this example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;
class Weight {
    int k;
    char a[100];
public:
    Weight(int kilos = 0) 
        :k(kilos) {}
    Weight(const Weight& w) 
        : k(w.k) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) this->a[i] = 'a'; 
        cout << "WCC\n";
    }
    friend Weight operator+(const Weight& a, const Weight& b);
    Weight& operator=(const Weight & w) {
        this->k = w.k;
        return *this;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Weight&);
};
Weight operator+(const Weight& a, const Weight& b) {
    cout << "FP\n";
    int newkg = a.k + b.k;
    return Weight(newkg);
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Weight& w) {
    out << w.k << " KGs";
    return out;
}
class Container{
    Weight w;
    static Weight totalW;
    static int count;
public:
    Container(){++count;}
    ~Container(){cout << "CD\n";}
    Container& add(Weight weight) {
        this->w = this->w + weight; 
        totalW = totalW + weight;
        cout << "Just added a new item that weighs " << weight << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    static void print() { 
        cout << "We have " << count << " Containers with a total weight " 
                << totalW << endl;
    } 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Container&);
};
Weight Container::totalW;
int Container::count = 0;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Container& c){
    out << "This container's " << c.w;
    return out;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Container c1;

    Weight *w1 = new Weight(1);
    Weight *w2 = new Weight(2);
    Weight *w3 = new Weight(3);

    cout << "Adding items to container...\n";
    c1.add(*w1).add(*w2).add(*w3);

    cout << c1 << endl;

    Container::print();
    return 0;
}
```

And I got this output:

```
Adding items to container...
WCC
WCC
WCC
FP
FP
Just added a new item that weighs 1 KGs
FP
FP
Just added a new item that weighs 2 KGs
FP
FP
Just added a new item that weighs 3 KGs
This container's 6 KGs
We have 1 Containers with a total weight 6 KGs
CD
```

You can see that the copy constructor for the Weight class was called three times (Output lines 2-4) before any of the cascaded functions was called. I always thought that the left most function call will be performed before any copy constructor is called up to setup the second function call.

To be more specific, I thought this what should have happened:
WCC -> c1.add(*w1) -> WCC -> .add(*w2) -> WCC -> .add(*w3).

I thought this was necessary because the function argument will be stored in the function's stack frame. So, a stack frame needs to be setup before the copy constructor for the argument is called. Apparently, I am mistaken.

This makes me think that function arguments are store somewhere else other than the stack frame. So, where?

Do not mind the horrific coding style. This, obviously, is not meant to be in production code.

Comment: `add()` takes its parameter by value. For that, a copy of the argument must be made before the function is called. The order of evaluation of subexpressions within an expression is unspecified. Here, the compiler chose to make all three copies up front, before the three function calls. Interleaving the way you expect would also be a valid choice.

Comment: So, if the function has not been called yet which also means its stack frame is not setup yet. Where are these objects stored?

Comment: Possibly on registers; `Weight` is small enough to fit in a register. Possibly the copy constructors got inlined, and the three print statements got separated from the three `int` initializations and executed in a different order. If you care enough to want to know for sure, examine the generated assembly.

Comment: I added more fields to the class (see above) and also added more code to the copy constructor. I am getting the same output. I do not think the copy-constructed object is stored in a register.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the behavior [here](https://godbolt.org/g/129MXt). The disassembly for the three `add()` calls starts at line 202. I'm not really fluent in assembly, but what appears to happen is this: a space is reserved on the stack for three temporary instances of `Weight`. All three are created in this space, via an inlined copy constructor (lines 202-213, three nearly identical blocks that store a number to a stack location and then call `operator<<`). Finally, `add()` is called three times (lines 214-222): to each, the address of a corresponding temporary is passed on a register.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a basic compiler optimization. Since there's no requirement when a function's parameters should be initialized from supplied arguments, a compiler can do necessary optimization by rearranging them. That's why you see the copy constructors called all at once.

Comment: So, if the function has not been called yet which also means its stack frame is not setup yet. Where are these objects stored?